# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157) Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Null>

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm trying handle  error from http request in showDialog and then throw an error but i'm facing this bug

**Error**

> E/flutter (18769): #13     TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation 
>      package:flutter/…/services/text_input.dart:968 E/flutter (18769): #14
>      MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall 
>      package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:402 E/flutter
>      (18769): #15     MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.  package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:370
>      E/flutter (18769): #16
>      _DefaultBinaryMessenger.handlePlatformMessage  package:flutter/…/services/binding.dart:200 E/flutter (18769): #17
>      _invoke3.  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:303:15) E/flutter (18769): #18     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13) E/flutter
>      (18769): #19     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
>      E/flutter (18769): #20     _CustomZone.runGuarded 
>      (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7) E/flutter (18769): #21     _invoke3 
>      (dart:ui/hooks.dart:302:10) E/flutter (18769): #22
>      _dispatchPlatformMessage  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:162:5)

```
  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) {
    const url = 'https://flutter-shop-768a7.firebaseio.com/products.jon';
    return http
        .post(url,
            body: json.encode({
              'title': product.title,
              'description': product.description,
              'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
              'price': product.price,
              'isFavorite': product.isFavorite
            }))
        .then((response) {
      final newProduct = Product(
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
          price: product.price,
          id: json.decode(response.body)['name']);
      // _items.insert(index, element)
      _items.add(newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((error) {
      throw error;
    });
  }
```

```
     Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .addProduct(_edditedProduct)
          .catchError((error) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('An Error occurred!'),
            content: Text('Someghing went wrong'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('ok'),
                  onPressed: () async => Navigator.of(context).pop())
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).then((_) {
        print('this is then function');
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

it`s because your function type is Future and your return type must be Future
but when you face an error your response throw an Error and return Null so its better to write your async function like this

```
addProduct(Product product) async {
    const url = 'https://flutter-shop-768a7.firebaseio.com/products.json';
    await http
        .post(url,
            body: json.encode({
              'title': product.title,
              'description': product.description,
              'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
              'price': product.price,
              'isFavorite': product.isFavorite
            }))
        .then((response) {
      final newProduct = Product(
          title: product.title,
          description: product.description,
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
          price: product.price,
          id: json.decode(response.body)['name']);
      // _items.insert(index, element)
      _items.add(newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((error) {
      throw error;
    });
  }
```

and your url is incorrect change `'https://flutter-shop-768a7.firebaseio.com/products.jon'` to `'https://flutter-shop-768a7.firebaseio.com/products.json'`

Answer (score 1):

Please add 'Null' below like this. I am also facing the same issue after adding the issue is resolved.

```
    return showDialog<Null>(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error occurred!'),
        content: Text('Something went wrong...'),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Okay')),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened because you didn't specify the return type of `.then((response) {})` method, to solve this simply change

```
 .then((response) {
  final newProduct = Product(
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      price: product.price,
      id: json.decode(response.body)['name']);
  // _items.insert(index, element)
  _items.add(newProduct);
  notifyListeners();
})
```

to

```
.then<void>((response) {
  final newProduct = Product(
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      price: product.price,
      id: json.decode(response.body)['name']);
  // _items.insert(index, element)
  _items.add(newProduct);
  notifyListeners();
})de here
```